# Ordenar columnas de un GridView en ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ordenamiento

Quiero ordenar las columnas de un GridView en ASP.NET, estoy consumiendo un servicio externo que me arroja ya los resultados y ese resultado yo lo he  puesto en una grilla, es decir en un `GridView` pero lo que quiero es ordenar por columnas.

**Este es mi codigo :**

```
ServiceReference1.SvcCreditoExternoClient tabla = new ServiceReference1.SvcCreditoExternoClient();
ServiceReference1.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest dtorequest = new ServiceReference1.DtoGeneradorTablaAmortizacionRequest();
ServiceReference1.DtoDividendo dtodividendo = new ServiceReference1.DtoDividendo();
List<ServiceReference1.DtoDividendo> listadtodividendo;

dtorequest.AjustarTabla = ServiceReference1.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioMetodosAjusteTabla.SinAjuste;
dtorequest.AplicaAlgoritmoRedondeoCuota = true;
dtorequest.AplicaDiaLaborable = true;
dtorequest.AplicaDiaLaborableFinSemanaAdelante = true;
dtorequest.AplicaFechasIguales = true;
dtorequest.AplicaFindeMes = true;
dtorequest.AplicaPrimerVencimiento = true;
dtorequest.BaseCalculo = 360;
dtorequest.CodigoSectorOrganismoControl = 0;
dtorequest.Decimales = 2;
dtorequest.DecimalesCuota = 2;
dtorequest.DecimalesTasa = 2;
dtorequest.EsExento = false;
dtorequest.FactorDeRedondeo = ServiceReference1.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioFactorRedondeo.SnDecimales;
dtorequest.Fecha1erVencimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFechaDesembolso.Text);//Convert.ToDateTime("2016-07-06");
dtorequest.FechaInicioTabla = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-05-29");
//FormaPago = 12,
dtorequest.GeneraTasaObjetivo = false;
dtorequest.Gradiente = 0;
dtorequest.Idproducto = 1;
dtorequest.Institucion = 1;

Decimal FactorMaximo;
FactorMaximo = Convert.ToDecimal(150000);
Decimal TasaMensual;
TasaMensual = Convert.ToDecimal(0.08);
Decimal TasaDiaria;
TasaDiaria = Convert.ToDecimal((TasaMensual / 30) / 100);
Session["2"] = TasaDiaria;
Decimal Plazo;
Plazo = Convert.ToInt32(dprNumerocuota.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(0, 2)) * 30;
Decimal factor1, factor2;
factor1 = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtImporteCredito.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(Plazo) * Convert.ToDecimal(TasaDiaria)) + Convert.ToDecimal(txtImporteCredito.Text);
Session["3"] = factor1;
factor2 = Convert.ToDecimal(factor1) * Convert.ToInt32(Plazo) * Convert.ToDecimal(TasaDiaria);
Session["4"] = factor2;
Decimal SeguroDesgravamen;
SeguroDesgravamen = (Convert.ToDecimal(factor1) > Convert.ToDecimal(FactorMaximo) ? Convert.ToDecimal(FactorMaximo) : Convert.ToDecimal(factor2));
Session["5"] = SeguroDesgravamen;
Decimal MontoFinanciado;
MontoFinanciado = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(txtImporteCredito.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(SeguroDesgravamen), 2);
Session["6"] = MontoFinanciado;
Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(MontoFinanciado);

//ListaRubroDiferido = Rubrio.Add(pag),
dtorequest.Monto = MontoFinanciado;//Convert.ToDecimal(txtImporteCredito.Text);//Convert.ToDecimal(1900.00);
dtorequest.MontoCapitalFijo = 0;
dtorequest.MontoTIR2 = 10000;
dtorequest.MontoTIR3 = 0;
int somestring = Convert.ToInt32(dprNumerocuota.SelectedItem.Value);
dtorequest.NumeroCuotas = Convert.ToInt32(dprNumerocuota.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(0, 2));// 12;
dtorequest.Oficina = 5;
dtorequest.Periodicidad = 30;
dtorequest.PeriodicidadCapital = 0;
dtorequest.PeriodicidadInteres = 0;
dtorequest.PeriodosGracia = 0;
dtorequest.Plazo = Convert.ToInt32(dprNumerocuota.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(0, 2)) * 30;

Session["7"] = dtorequest.Plazo;
Session["8"] = Convert.ToInt32(dprNumerocuota.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(0, 2));

dtorequest.PorcentajeMinimoCuoton = 0;
dtorequest.RedondeoHacia = ServiceReference1.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioTipoRedondeo.Arriba;   
dtorequest.Tasa = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTEA.Text);//40;
dtorequest.TasaInicialObjetivo = 0;
dtorequest.TipoGracia = ServiceReference1.EnumeradosConfiguracionNegocioTipoGracia.GraciaCapital;
dtorequest.TipoTabla = "CUOTFIJA";

listadtodividendo = tabla.ConsultarTablaAmortizacion(dtorequest).ToList();

GridView1.DataSource = listadtodividendo;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

Al principio cuando ejecuté me salían varias filas que no deseaba, entonces las oculté.

Realmente, solo necesito la ordenación.

Yo quiera ordenarlas así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero a me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando dices `filas`...te refieres a `columnas`?

Comment: @Pikoh si a las columnas del gridview.

Comment: El gridview tiene activado el `AutoGenerateColumns`?

Comment: @Pikoh no solo esta activado el OnRowCreated

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"></asp:GridView>

Comment: O sea,que si,ya que por defecto está activado. Tu no estás definiendo las columnas, si no que se generan automáticamente al asignar el datasource. En ese caso, puedes por ejemplo cambiar el orden de las propiedades en tu clase `ServiceReference1.DtoDividendo`

Comment: @Pikoh si mi hermano esque ese servicio ya por defecto me vota esa columnas , esque yo ese servicio no le creado es de un tercero.

Comment: Entonces debes configurar las columnas a mano. [Aqui tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado que llena el `GridView` lo estás obteniendo en una lista, entonces, ahí es donde se puede aplica qué columnas van primero, y cuales después. Usando Linq, puedes tomar la lista original y a partir de ahí crear una nueva que servirá como la fuente de datos del `GridView`:

```
//Aquí va todo el código que actualmente tienes
listadtodividendo = tabla.ConsultarTablaAmortizacion(dtorequest).ToList();

var nuevolistadtodividendo = (from o in listadtodividendo
                select new {
                    Capital = o.Capital
                    Cuota = o.Cuota
                }).Tolist();

GridView1.DataSource = nuevolistadtodividendo;
//Aquí va todo el código que actualmente tienes
```

Lo único que tienes que hacer, es poner en la sección del `select` las columnas que desees y en automático se ordenarán.